# How to create entries with image element in the RSS Feed using the java ROME API?

Tags: java, rss, rome

I am trying to create the RSS Feeds using java ROME API. My requirement is that every entry should contain an Image as given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Sample RSS Build Results</title>
    <link>http://time.is</link>
    <description>sample RSS build</description>
        <item>
          <title>Ist Feed</title>
          <link>http://mysampleurl1.com</link>
          <description>The build was successful!</description>
          <pubDate>Mon, 08 Aug 2016 10:28:32 GMT</pubDate>
          <image>http://myimageurl1.com</image>
          <dc:date>2016-08-08T10:28:32Z</dc:date>
        </item>
        <item>
          <title>IInd Feed</title>
          <link>http://mysampleurl2.com</link>
          <description>The build was successful!</description>
          <pubDate>Mon, 08 Aug 2016 10:28:44 GMT</pubDate>
          <dc:date>2016-08-08T10:28:44Z</dc:date>
        </item>
</channel>
```

I am new to java ROME api. It provides the package :: `com.rometools.rome.feed.synd.SyndImageImpl` to set/get image item in complete feed but not in individual entries. For an entry in RSS feed it has package :: `com.rometools.rome.feed.synd.SyndEntryImpl` but it does not provide any function for setting or getting image.

Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[The RSS spec](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) doesn't specify image elements for entries, but you can extend it with [Image namespace](http://web.resource.org/rss/1.0/modules/image/).

Short solution could be like this:

```
SyndEntry entry = new SyndEntryImpl();
..
Element image = new Element("image", Namespace.getNamespace("image", "http://web.resource.org/rss/1.0/modules/image/"));
image.addContent("http://localhost/feed/item1_image");
entry.getForeignMarkup().add(image);
```

This will result in valid xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>title</title>
    <link>http://localhost/feed</link>
    <description>description</description>
    <item>
      <title>entry title 1</title>
      <link>http://localhost/feed/item1</link>
      <image:image xmlns:image="http://web.resource.org/rss/1.0/modules/image/">http://localhost/feed/item1_image</image:image>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">http://localhost/feed/item1</guid>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

More robust way is to [create a custom module](https://rometools.github.io/rome/RssAndAtOMUtilitiEsROMEV0.5AndAboveTutorialsAndArticles/RssAndAtOMUtilitiEsROMEV0.5TutorialDefiningACustomModuleBeanParserAndGenerator.html) like they've done [here](http://www.gridshore.nl/2010/02/16/creating-a-w3c-validated-rss-feed-using-rome-and-spring-3/) and [here](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2011/02/14/all-roads-lead-to-rome/).

Comment: What package does `Element` come from? Please include imports...

Comment: From [jdom2](http://jdom.org). It is also a dependency in rometools. Packages are `org.jdom2.Element`and `org.jdom2.Namespace`.