# Need to extend ROME's default RSS feed schema/generator

Tags: java, xml, rss, rome

I need to add some fields and a namespace to an existing RSS feed built in ROME. A rather simple operation in theory, but I'm struggling. I figured all I'd have to do is extend SyndEntry/SyndEntryImpl and SyndFeed/SyndFeedImpl, putting the new fields in those new classes/interfaces. But apparently not?

This is a legacy application and it only does generation not consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a custom module for you namespace, see [this tutorial](https://rometools.github.io/rome/RssAndAtOMUtilitiEsROMEV0.5AndAboveTutorialsAndArticles/RssAndAtOMUtilitiEsROMEV0.5TutorialDefiningACustomModuleBeanParserAndGenerator.html) or this old answer: [How to create entries with image element in the RSS Feed using the java ROME API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829416/how-to-create-entries-with-image-element-in-the-rss-feed-using-the-java-rome-api/38917885#38917885)